# Need help clarifying my python script to run on Rpi3b+

Tags: python, pi-3b+

If it's not obvious, I'm trying to learn python, and am having a go at it.  Although, I'm running into some issues.  Any help would be appreciated.
I'm trying to run this on a Rpi3b+ & with a relay

Edit: What I'm trying to do is have the script check the water level first before the it activates the pump relay, but I can't even get the script to pass a debug run through. Or is there a better way to write this script that will work with a Rpi?

```
# Hydroponic Watering v.0.0.1
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import signal

signal.signal(signal.sigint, GPIO)

# Setting GPIO pins on Rpi
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
signal, resv_level_pin, GPIO.in, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_up = 18
pump_relay, GPIO.OUT = 9

def check_water_level
    if resv_level_pin == true
    pump_relay(on)
    elif resv_level_pin == false
        pump_relay(false)
        print("Water level too low!")

exit(sys.exit)
```

Debug output as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mu-editor/mu/mu-debug.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mu.app import debug
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mu'


---------- FINISHED ----------
exit code: 1 status: 0
```

Comment: I still wonder that any of this works. `signal.signal(signal.sigint, GPIO)` is certainly not what you intend it to be. What is `signal, resv_level_pin, GPIO.in, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_up = 18` supposed to mean? Your function definition lacks the parentheses, the parameters (if any) and the colon. It is furthermore never called. `if` and `elif` lack the colon too and the indentation is off after `if`. Where there is the `elif` an `else` should suffice. `True` and `False` keywords should start uppercase.

Comment: The final `exit(sys.exit)` is not only superfluous but also a strange combination of two things. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747371/3984613). It should be `exit()` or `sys.exit()` with the parameter being the error code if you intend to send one to the caller.

Comment: The answer may have indicated 
your immediate problem, but the code listed still has code errors, logic errors and will actually do nothing. I suggest you look at [GPIO Zero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html) which has helpful tutorials.

Comment: @hanlok Please understand that literally asking other people to write code for you ("is there a better way to write this script that will work") is kind of a non-starter. Based on the errors other people have pointed out, you need to get down to basics; if you don't understand those you will just have one error after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Mu to run that python file, and it (**not your script**) is returning an error:

```
  File "/usr/share/mu-editor/mu/mu-debug.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mu.app import debug
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mu'
```

I reccomend trying that code with Python IDLE, or [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) -- which should have come with Raspbian.

Comment: @hanlok, if you have any further problems, don't hesitate to post 'em here.

Answer (score 0):

After using a different editor, I learned that I had all kinds of problems, like not understanding what I was trying to accomplish, but after getting away from the screen and coming back with fresh eyes, I ended up with the follow script which works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Hydroponic Watering v.0.0.1
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import datetime

sys.stdout=open("test.txt","a")
timestamp = time.strftime("Time: %H:%M, Date: %Y%m%d, ")

# Setting GPIO pins on Rpi
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
switch1=18
pump_relay=26
refill_relay=21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(switch1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pump_relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(refill_relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(switch1, GPIO.LOW)

# Check Water Level
switch1_is_on = GPIO.input(switch1)

# Activate pump_relay
if switch1_is_on:
    GPIO.output(26,1)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(timestamp,"Water level OK.")
    GPIO.output(26,0)
else:
    GPIO.output(21,1)
    time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(21,0)
    print(timestamp,"Water level is too low!")
```